# Kendo grid detail template does not apply correctly

Tags: angularjs, kendo-grid, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to render a kendo grid detail template. The grid is correctly rendered. However, for some reason, I don't see the expand icon. I also see the contents of the detail template rendered above the grid (without the dataItem bound to it though).

```
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="MainController">
      <tabset>
        <tab heading="A">
          <grid-demo grid-options="gridOptions"></grid-demo>
        </tab>
        <tab heading="B"></tab>
      </tabset>
    </div>
  </body>
```

JavaScript:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['kendo.directives', 'ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MainController', ['$scope',
  function($scope) {
    $scope.data = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([{
      status: 1,
      requestor: 'Alex',
      approver: 'Jim',
      whenRequested: '01-22-2015'
    }, {
      status: 2,
      requestor: 'Peter',
      approver: 'Tanisha',
      whenRequested: '01-22-2015'
    }, {
      status: 3,
      requestor: 'Peter',
      approver: 'Tanisha',
      whenRequested: '01-22-2015'
    }]);

    $scope.gridOptions = {
      dataSource: $scope.data,
      sortable: true,
      scrollable: false,
      columns: [{
        field: "status",
        title: "status",
        template: "{{dataItem.status}}"
      }, {
        field: "requestor",
        title: "requestor",
        template: "{{dataItem.requestor}}"
      }, {
        field: "approver",
        title: "approver",
        template: "{{dataItem.approver}}"
      }, {
        field: "whenRequested",
        title: "whenRequested",
        template: "{{dataItem.whenRequested}}"
      }]
    };
  }
]);

app.directive('gridDemo', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {
      gridOptions: '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'gridDemo.htm',
    link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
    }
  };
});
```

gridDemo.htm Template

```
<div kendo-grid="demoGrid" k-options="gridOptions">
  <div k-detail-template>
    <a href="">Status{{dataItem.status}}</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is the [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/b6UED4O0jNz69ShhMv4x)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What expand icon are you talking about?

Comment: Because I have a k-detail-template inside my grid, for each item in the grid, I should see a small arrow with which i can see the details of each item. See example on kendo for details http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/angular

Comment: Can someone please help me resolve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is how I came to the solution:

1. I've updated Kendo UI to the newest version - **2014.3.1411**.
2. After this update there was JavaScript error: `Error: [$compile:multidir] Multiple directives [gridDemo, kendoGrid] asking for template on: <kendo-grid k-options="gridOptions" grid-options="gridOptions">` so I put `replace: false` in definition of **grid-demo** directive
3. Then I got JavaScript error: `Error: Invalid template: ...` and I figured out that the problem was with **#** sign in **k-detail-template directive**. I escaped this sign using **\#**
4. This fixed JavaScript errors but **k-detail-template** was still not visible so I removed `class="ng-hide"` from the template
5. Now all was fine except for **k-detail-template** content that appeared visible before the grid. Moving **grid-demo** out of **tabset** solved the issue. The problem is that Kendo does not delete the template definition when inside of **tabset**

As a quick work around to the last problem I added two classes in **grid-demo**:

```
  <kendo-grid class="demo-grid" k-options="gridOptions">
    <div class="detail-template" class="" k-detail-template>
      <a href="\#">Status{{dataItem.status}}</a>
    </div>
  </kendo-grid>
```

And I hid **k-detail-template** definition with CSS selector:

```
.demo-grid > .detail-template {
  display: none;
}
```

See the solution in [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Kh7fykcoClQ9l7MPR8zK).

Comment: Thank you for helping resolving this issue. Looks like i was not referencing the correct version of kendo library. Why does Kendo not hide the template in tabset? You have provided a work around for hiding the template. Is there something I can do in tabset or the grid for me to enable hiding it?

Comment: @vaibinewbee the template gets added when using bootstrap ui tabset but not with kendo tabstrip http://plnkr.co/edit/0bE1VzcpCZUF4YgYh6S0?p=preview the reason may be kendo grid takes time to render and bootstrap ui tabset takes it as normal tag and renders it (which can be seen in element tab of developer tools)